# Cant format partition

Tags: partitioning, formatting

I want to format my E: partition, but from the disk manager menu its disabled, and access is denied from powershell.

[image: Image of drive and partitions.]

How do I get this to work?

Comment: I know little about Windows, but your problem may be because the page file is there. Can you move it out of the way? What Windows is it?

Answer (score 3):

A partition with the pagefile cannot be formatted or deleted.
You first need to disable the pagefile, or move it to another disk.
If you wish the pagefile to be on the formatted E, disable it now
and re-enable after the format. You should not stay permanently
without having any pagefile, only temporarily.

- Run *Control Panel > System*
- Click "Advanced system settings"
- Navigate to the "Advanced" tab
- Under Performance, click Settings
- Navigate to the Advanced tab
- Under Virtual memory, click Change
- Untick "Automatically manage paging..."
- Select drive `E:` and click 'No paging file'
- Click Set
- Click OK on all.

You may, the same way, pick `C:` as the disk for housing a new pagefile.